# Subscript out of range error on a VBA procedure with Ranges and Arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting

I have written the following VBA Code to calculate some threshold value, and at one point I place values from a Range into an array. However, I get a "Subscript out of range" error though I think I have defined everything.

Or is it ValeursAction() As Variant that is incorrect? It is supposed to be an array... and I am sorting it with Call Tri1(ValeursAction).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Performance()
Dim N As Long
Dim EnsembleActions As Range
Dim Nb_Actions As Integer
Dim Action As Range
Dim CoursAction As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim SharpeRatio As Double
Dim TauxRf As Double
Dim RendsEcart As Double
Dim NomAction As String
Dim ValeursAction() As Variant
Dim NB As Integer

    With Worksheets("Actions")
        Nb_Actions = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    With Worksheets("Actions")
        Set EnsembleActions = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, Nb_Actions).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each Action In EnsembleActions.Columns
        i = i + 1
        Set CoursAction = Action

        TauxRf = Worksheets("Performance").Cells(2, 2).Value
        RendsEcart = WorksheetFunction.StDev(CoursAction)

         NB = WorksheetFunction.Count(CoursAction)

        'We place values from the range in a table
        With Worksheets("Actions")
            ValeursAction = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)).Value
        End With

    'Sorting the array
    Call Tri1(ValeursAction)

    Dim alpha As Double
    Dim Var As Double

        alpha = Worksheets("Performance des fonds").Cells(3, 2).Value

        Var = ValeursAction(Int(NB * alpha))


        NomAction = Worksheets("Actions").Cells(1, i).Value

    With Worksheets("Performance")
        .Cells(4 + i, 1) = NomAction

        .Cells(4 + i, 2) = Var

    End With
Next Action

End Sub

Sub Tri1(plaga As Variant)
Dim ligne_Deb As Long
Dim ligne_Fin As Long

ligne_Deb = LBound(plaga)
ligne_Fin = UBound(plaga)

Dim i As Long, J As Long
Dim tmp As Long

For i = ligne_Deb To ligne_Fin - 1
    For J = ligne_Fin To i + 1 Step -1
        If plaga(J, 1) < plaga(J - 1, 1) Then
            tmp = plaga(J, 1)
            plaga(J, 1) = plaga(J - 1, 1)
            plaga(J - 1, 1) = tmp
        End If
    Next J
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line generates the error?

Comment: Have you confused a 0-based object with a 1-based object? It's easy to forget which ones are which.

Comment: I don't think so... this code worked perfectly fine before I added the array ValeursAction...

Comment: add this under 'Option Explicit':
Option Base 0

Answer (score 0):

The arrays (ValeursAction/plaga) that you are auto-dimensioning have ones-based dimensions, *not* zero-based.  But for these lines:

```
    If plaga(J, 1) < plaga(J - 1, 1) Then
        tmp = plaga(J, 1)
        plaga(J, 1) = plaga(J - 1, 1)
        plaga(J - 1, 1) = tmp
    End If
```

The loop counter `J` will decrement down to 1, so that `J - 1` is zero, which is out of your array's bound.

Comment: So Should I place Option Base 1 for the first sub too?

Comment: No, you need to change the code above so that it stops trying to access zero.

Comment: I tried both by adding option base 1 and option base 0 and i still get that error :(